# ng-switch not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, angular-ng-if, ng-switch

Instead of having two separate `ng-if`, I want to combine them and use `ng-switch`. However, the `img()` functions are not switching as expected. What should I do differently?

Turn this:

```
<img ng-src="{{img(myColor)}}" ng-if="myColor">

<img ng-src="{{img(myColor2)}}" ng-if="myColor2">
```

Into this:

```
<div ng-switch on = "myColor2">
    <div ng-switch-when = "myColor2">
        <img ng-src="{{img(myColor2)}}">
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default = "myColor">
        <img ng-src="{{img(myColor)}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just in case, it's `ng-switch-default`, not `ng-switch default`

Comment: @iggymoran thanks for the catch. That didn't fix it though

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for ng-switch

http://jsfiddle.net/fbg3bLac/5/

You might be understanding it wrong.

```
ng-switch on = "myColor2" -- means you want to evaluate the value of the scope variable myColor2.

ng-switch-when = "myColor2" -- states that if the VALUE of myColor2 is equal to 'myColor2' then do this.

ng-switch-default -- should have no = value.
```

Please refer to http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/switch-condition-in-angularjs/

Comment: thanks, is there no way to accomplish what I am trying to do? I see what you are saying but I have two different ng-models

Comment: example you want to switch the scope variable color and then your switch would be ng-switch-when="{{myColor1}}" -- haven't tried yet but it should let angular know that myColor1 is a variable to be evaluated and not a value itself.